# How to Use the sheets API

Tags: android, google-sheets

Hi I am from a robotics team and trying to use the sheets API to put data into google sheets but at the competition we have no internet connection so we save the data locally then we want to upload it into a sheet that is stored on the tablet and then it will be in so that when the tablet connects to the internet the table is updated. So far we have the local save working but google sheets is proving confusing. We  need to have this done by saturday preferably tuesday thanks for all the help

```
 package com.scouting.corbin.frc_201415_scouting;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.TextConstruct;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;



public class SheetSaver
{
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("test");
SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet;
WorksheetEntry entry;
URL worksheetUrl;
ListFeed feed;
int length = 100;
int ind = 0;

public SheetSaver() throws Exception
{
    spreadsheet = new SpreadsheetEntry();
    spreadsheet.setTitle(TextConstruct.create(1, "TestSheet", null));
    entry = spreadsheet.getDefaultWorksheet();
    entry.setColCount(2);
    entry.setRowCount(length);
    worksheetUrl = entry.getCellFeedUrl();
    feed = service.getFeed(worksheetUrl, ListFeed.class);
}

void save()
{

}

void add(int value) throws IOException, ServiceException
{
    ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
    row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("test", String.valueOf(value));
    service.insert(worksheetUrl, row);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to do something similar I looked at the Google Sheets API and decided that it wasn't worth it - thankfully I found the Google Drive API to be much easier. Take a look at the resources here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files

With this you won't be able to directly write to a Google Sheets file but alternatively you can create a CSV file and write data as CSV (comma-separated-values) which is really easy. The Google Drive API handles all of the local sync and storage itself. I'm not quite sure how Google Sheets handles authentication but from what I saw it looked quite complicated.

With Google Drive you can use the Google Plus API and the built in permissions stuff to do it quite easily (Log in buttons, permission screen, etc) are all provided.

Having done FIRST myself (FTC) - you could just use one of the existing scouting apps [here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=first%20robotics%20scouting&c=apps&hl=en).

Unless this is for judging - then good luck :P.